# Laravel 5 - return only one field from relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

have a relationship which returns rows from a pivot table.

However I just want to return a collection of the user ids from the table.

If I have it as current:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower')->select(array('project_id', 'user_id'));
}
```

It will return the 2 fields, but if I just have the select with a single field:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower')->select( 'user_id');
}
```

It returns an an empty object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this function is in your `Project` model. When modifying the `select` on a relationship, you must, at a minimum, select the fields needed to match the records together.

In this case, if this in on your `Project` model, if you don't select the `project_id` from the related table, Laravel can't match up the `Follower` objects with the correct `Project` objects, since Laravel won't have any idea which `Project` the `Follower` belongs to without the foreign key.